# How to replace variable in properties file through jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to replace variable in a properties file. I have tried below code but its not working. Every time I run build instead of replacing the variable its duplicating it.

```
def readContent = readFile 'test.properties'
writeFile file: 'test.properties', text: readContent+"\r\nREL_VERSION=v=${env.ReleaseNumber}"
```

current output is :

```
nREL_VERSION=v=2
nREL_VERSION=v=3
```

Comment: That's exactly what you've written it to do.

Comment: But, I want to replace or overwrite existing variable instead of dulplicating it

Comment: Depends on what your file looks like. but try this to just replace old v new:

def readContent = readFile 'test.properties'
updatedProp = readContent.replaceAll("REL_VERSION=.*", "REL_VERSION=v=${env.ReleaseNumber}")
writeFile file: 'test.properties', text: "${updatedProp}"

Answer (score 1):

An easy option will be to use the [readProperties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) keyword which will load the properties file in to a map, then update the relevant values and write the new content to the file:

```
def readContent = readProperties 'test.properties'
// Update Values
readContent.REL_VERSION = "v=${env.ReleaseNumber}"
...
writeContent = readContent.collect{"${it.key}=${it.value}"}.join('\n')
writeFile file: 'test.properties', text: writeContent
```

Comment: nice hint for that collect which is needed to map a Properties to String, it's weird that the original library itself does not have the write back method for properties

Comment: Indeed wired, i think there is a feature request opened for that somewhere. Maybe it is because there are several formats possible for the properties files...